# Proving that every non-negative integer has an unique binary expansion with generating functions

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

Could you tell me how can I prove that every non-zero integer has an unique binary expansion using the generating functions, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the infinite product

$$P=\prod_{n=0}^\infty (1+x^{2^n}).$$

This is a convergent product in the $x$-adic metric (under which the formal power series ring $R[[x]]$ is complete for any ring $R$, more or less by definition). Indeed, the $n^{\text{th}}$ term of the products affects only terms with degree $\geq 2^n$.

If you expand it out, you find that it can be written as

$$\sum_{m=0}^\infty c_mx^m$$

where $c_m$ is the number of ways of writing $m$ as a sum of distinct powers of $2$.

On the other hand, consider $(1-x)P_N$, where $P_N$ denotes the $N$th partial product of the infinite product above. It is easy to see that $(1-x)P_N=1-x^{2^{N}}$. Hence, taking the limit, we see that $(1-x)P=1$. This implies $P=1+x+x^2+\dots$, hence $c_m=1$ for all $m$ and $m$ has a unique binary representation.

Answer (score 1):

Hi this is my first time posting so pls point out if I made any mistakes.

I want to expand on the answer above:

The generating function for binary expansion $B(x)$ is
$$B(x)={(1+x)}{(1+x^2)}{(1+x^4)}{(1+x^8)}...{(1+x^{2^j})}...$$
This means that I either use a part of size 1 or not at all, and I either use a part of size 2 or not at all, ... This corresponds to the 0 and 1 digit in the binary expansion, 0 meaning not use a part and 1 means use a part exactly 1 time.
We want to show that each $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$ has unique binary expansion means we want to show the coefficient of each $x^n$ is 1. Fix an $n\in \mathbb{N}_0$. We know there exists a $k\in \mathbb{N}$ such that $2^k>n$. Consider the following steps
\begin{align}
    B(x) &= 1\cdot {(1+x)}{(1+x^2)}{(1+x^4)}{(1+x^8)}...{(1+x^{2^j})}...\\
    &= \frac{1-x}{1-x}{(1+x)}{(1+x^2)}{(1+x^4)}{(1+x^8)}...{(1+x^{2^j})}...\\
    &= \frac{1-x^2}{1-x}{(1+x^2)}{(1+x^4)}{(1+x^8)}...{(1+x^{2^j})}...\\
    &=\frac{1-x^4}{1-x}{(1+x^4)}{(1+x^8)}...{(1+x^{2^j})}...\\
    &...\\
    &=\frac{1-x^{2^{k+1}}}{1-x}{(1+x^{2^{k+1}})}...
\end{align}
Note since $2^k>n$, the factors $(1-x^{2^{k+1}}), (1+x^{2^{k+1}}),...$ or any factor later would not contribute to the term $x^n$, so the only contributing factor is $\frac{1}{1-x}$, and we know $x^n$ has coefficient 1 in $\frac{1}{1-x}$.